# How to make borders around fontawesome glyphs match visuals

Tags: css, font-awesome

If you run the following code snippet, you can see that the border around the fontawesome glyphs specified by `.item` doesn't quite line up with the glyph's visuals, causing `:hover`-based to be less than perfect.  I have tested this using

- Firefox Version 61.0.2 (64-bit)

[image: Firefox result]

- Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

```css
/* show some text */
div {
  text-align: center;
}

abbr[showMe] {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 300%;
}

abbr[showMe]:hover:after {
  content: attr(showMe);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<p>Hover to see my info</p>
<div>
  <abbr class="item" showMe="555 555 5555">
    <i class="fas fa-mobile text-secondary"></i>
  </abbr>
</div>
<div>
  <abbr class="item" showMe="email at domain dot com">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope text-secondary"></i>
  </abbr>
</div>
```

What should I do to make the border wrap neatly for any and all icons I use? I'm not above creating my own SVGs as a last resort, if there's not an easy (or hard, but cool ;) ) solution to this problem.

Comment: you are using SVG so the viewbox is controling this, I don't think you can adjust it since it's different fo each icon. When you check the icon page you can see the boundary of the SVG: https://fontawesome.com/icons/envelope?style=solid

Comment: even if it's not the SVG it will be the same with the CSS version